# Remove non selected node from dom

Tags: java, dom, itext

Background: Converting html form output to pdf using iText and want to have only selected value. If there are three options and user has selected option C as below, would like to show C only in pdf.

```
<input type="radio" name="test" value="A">A
<input type="radio" name="test" value="B">B
<input type="radio" name="test" value="C" checked="true">C
```

For above set of string, as only option "C" is selected, I would like to get following output:

```
<input type="radio" name="test" value="C">C
```

Basically, want to remove non selected node. Tried following way and did not get expected output.

```
NodeList list = node.getChildNodes();
     for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
          Element currentNode = null;
           if(list.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && list.item(i).getNodeName().equals("input") )
               currentNode =(Element) list.item(i);
                if(conditionDefinedForNotchecked && currentNode != null)
                    currentNode.getParentNode().removeChild(currentNode);
       }
```

Comment: Where is `currentNode` ever set? Seems it is always `null` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I love iText, but I still found creating an intermediate HTML format made my life much easier, simply because HTML debugging/viewing is much more advanced than PDF.

Suggested process:

1. Real HTML
2. [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/_) to convert to simplified HTML stripped of all unused elements + all sizes specified
3. IText output.